# C# VS- Must declare the scalar variable "@Globals"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

1C# VS- Must declare the scalar variable "@Globals"

Comment: You can't have a . in your param name. So change "@Globals.currentUserId" to "@GlobalsCurrentUserId", - It doesn't need to match the name of your C# variable

Comment: Or try to escape it in both the query and the parameter name: `@\"Globals.currentUserId\"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a . in your param name. So change

```
@Globals.currentUserId
```

to

```
 @GlobalsCurrentUserId
```

- It doesn't need to match the name of your C# variable

Answer (score 1):

The "." in the @Globals.currentUserId is creating the problem. It is a reserved character. Rename it to something like @UserId as shown below.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ElearningConnectionString2);
        string sc;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        sc = "INSERT INTO tblUserAnswers (UserId, QuizDate, score) values (@UserId, @QuizDate, @Score)";              
         cmd = new SqlCommand(sc, conn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Globals.currentUserId);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizDate", DateTime.Now);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", score);
        conn.Open();
        int re = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        if (re == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record saved");
        }
```

Comment: its now giving me this error . Incorrect syntax near '('.

Must declare the scalar variable "@GETDATE".

Comment: Change the @GETDATE() to @QuizDate